# Is my avocado dead after pruning?

Tags: pruning, avocado

I pruned my 1 year old avocado plant a few months ago and now when it shoots new leaves they die before being able to branch out or become big. [image]Have I killed my avocado? Is there anything I can do to help it now?

Comment: I wanted to ask the same question! I pruned 3, they were younger though, and they have remained the same (with the blackening side). One started growing a little green bit, but has remained the same for months...